Why ‘if not the citizen is ≥ 35’ ≡ ‘if the citizen is not ≥ 35’?
Baronett, Stan. Logic (5th ed, 2022). For brevity, let "president" be POTUS.

        In order to translate the statement “A citizen cannot be president unless the citizenis at least 35 years old,” we need to  understand how the word “unless” gets translated.
In most statements, the word “unless” means if not. Substituting this into the original statement gives us this result: ⚠ “A citizen cannot be president if the citizen is not at least
35 years old.”

Baronett skipped a step at ⚠, as direct substitution yields
A citizen can't be POTUS $\color{forestgreen}{if}$ $\color{red}{not}$ the citizen is ≥ 35 $\tag{2}$
Why can't you just leave the $\color{red}{not}$ here in (2)? Baronett fails to spell out how (2) gives:
A citizen can't be POTUS $\color{forestgreen}{if}$ the citizen
is $\color{red}{not}$ ≥ 35  $\tag{3}$
What justifies you to move $\color{red}{not}$  to between "is" and "≥ 35"?

(2) obviously means (3), but (3) is grammatically correct while (2) isn't. This has nothing to do with mathematics, though.

Wordplay, that’s mainly what this is.

It's not even interesting wordplay.

@NaïmFavier "(2) obviously means (3)". this is NOT obvious to me. pls explain?

" A citizen can't be POTUS if not the citizen is ≥ 35 " is not in English and to view it as an english sentence it is gobbledeegook.  The statement should be something like: "The citizen can not be president if it is not the case that the citizen is $\ge 35$"   This is completely equivalent and "obviously" the same as saying "The citizen can not be president if the citizen is not $\ge 35$".

This is really an issue of English grammar, not mathematics. "if not the citizen is at least 35" is not grammatically correct in English. It needs to be expressed as "if the citizen is not at least 35".  That's all.

But it can be expressed as "If it is not the case that the citizen is at least $35$". ... We could discuss if there is any technical difference between $\lnot(c \ge 35)$ and $c \not \ge 35$ but... let's not and say we did.
